# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch but input is correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to follow a GoRails [notifications tutorial](https://gorails.com/episodes/in-app-navbar-notifications) and am running into issues.
I got the error 
`ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch - User(#125297720) expected, got 1 which is an instance of Integer(#20118600):`
The odd thing is 1 is the user_id I am looking for, I am just not sure why it isn't saving it.

Code:
messages_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @message = Message.create user: current_user,
                                       room: @room,
                                       message: params.dig(:message, :message)

    if @message.save!
      Notification.create!(recipient: @room.reciever_id, actor_id: current_user, action: "message", notifiable: @message)
      redirect_back(fallback_location: rooms_path)
    else
      render rooms_path
    end
  end
```

notification.rb

```
class Notification < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :actor, class_name: "User", optional: true
  belongs_to :notifiable, polymorphic: true

  scope :unread, -> {where(read_at: nil)}
end
```

user.rb

```
  has_many :messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "user_id"
  has_many :rooms, :foreign_key => "sender_id"

  has_many :notifications, foreign_key: :recipient_id
```

room.rb

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy,
         inverse_of: :room
  has_many :users, {:through=>:messages, :source=>"user"}

end
```

message.rb

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => "user_id"
  belongs_to :room, inverse_of: :messages


  def as_json(options)
    super(options).merge(user_name: [user.first_name, user.last_name].compact.join(' '))
  end
end
```

if I change the @room.reciever_id to current_user in Notification.create it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this right here:

```
 Notification.create!(recipient: @room.reciever_id, actor_id: current_user
```

you are basically doing it backward - you're passing an *id* as the `recipient` and a *record* as the `actor_id`.

Remember that if you're using the `_id` field you should be passing an id, and if you're using the association name (e.g. `recipient`) you should pass the actual record:

following should work:

```
 Notification.create!(recipient_id: @room.reciever_id, actor_id: current_user.id
```

If you had an association `receiver` on `Room`, you could say:

```
 Notification.create!(recipient: @room.reciever, actor: current_user
```

however this is slightly worse performance because it does 1 more database lookup (querying for the whole `@room.receiver` object instead of reading the `receiver_id` directly off `@room`)